# Asynchronous zle (zsh line editor)

Tags: shell, asynchronous, zsh, zsh-zle

I've modified my zsh to always guess/autosuggest what I'm trying to type by modifying `self-insert` to run a `guess` function that interprets and modifies `$BUFFER` after running the default `zle .self-insert`.

The problem is this `guess` function may take a while to execute, which means pasting a line of input takes some time (as the characters come one after another with maybe up to 1 second delay between each one), and on a slow machine the lag would be quite noticeable even when I'm typing the command.

What I'd like it to do is to terminate this `guess` function as soon as another key is typed by the user, as the original `guess` based on the previous `$BUFFER` is no longer relevant anyway. This way the keyboard input will not be blocked by the `guess` function, and the `guess` function will update the `$BUFFER` only when it manages to complete before another key is entered.

Any suggestion on how to do this would be very helpful.Thank you.